# Auto Arranging Cards based on due date in Trello

Tags: trello

Is there a way to have the cards arrange themselves automatically based on the due date that has been set?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. Currently there is an auto-arrange by vote idea that is very highly rated, and it might be good to add this request to that conversation, as the two would be very similar: https://trello.com/card/board/way-to-sort-column-by-votes/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4dd28b64728b921a5d1e7209

Answer (score 0):

You can't auto-arrange cards by due date, but, there is now a card view to display cards by due date.

Answer (score 0):

To set it to sort fully automatically within Trello is currently not possible, no.

With the Chrome extension [Ultimello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultimello-the-features-pa/hahbfgjfimnmogoinnenhheepfcphnmm) however, you may do that manually. It's still very valuable for large columns of items.

Comment: This extension was removed from the Chrome Web Store a few months ago. I wouldn't suggest using it.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done by using Butler. You can choose a Trigger such as "every day at 08:00 AM" or "every time a due date is added or moved" and the Action "sort list [list] by due date".

- https://trello.com/c/mxbtnZab/196-sort-list-to-do-by-due-date has a specific example.
- https://trello.com/c/bZH9iHxz/131-sorting-lists has more detail on sorting lists using Butler in general.